# Adding a 'enum' MySQL field type with Phinx Migrate

Tags: mysql, enums, migration, phinx

I'm trying to create a migration in Phinx (actually a rollback) which will create a enum type field in a MySQL DB. Having read the [docs](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#id1) I was under the impression that this should be pretty simple but it just fails every time.

```
$table = $this->table('mytable');
$table->addColumn('warmth','enum', array('limit' => array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'P', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'N')))
->save();
```

Unfortunately there's no easy way to have Phinx output the offending SQL query either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use latest version from master (above 0.5.x-dev):

```
$this->table('my_table')
->addColumn('status', 'enum', ['values' => ['enabled', 'disabled']])
->save();
```

Comment: For those who care, it's the same for `set` column type.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe for others it will be interesting that there is [another way](https://github.com/andriichuk/php-db-migrations-cookbook#adding-a-enum-column) to add an ENUM column

```
use Phinx\Db\Adapter\MysqlAdapter;
use Phinx\Db\Table\Column;

$this->table('posts')
    ->addColumn(
        (new Column())
            ->setName('status')
            ->setType(MysqlAdapter::PHINX_TYPE_ENUM)
            ->setValues([
                'draft', 'publish', 'private', 'trash',
            ])
    )
    ->update();
```